# Is there an analytic function $f : \mathbb{D} → \mathbb{D}$ with $f(0) = 1/2$ and $f′(0) = 3/4?$

Tags: complex-analysis

(a) Let $\mathbb{D}$ denote the unit disk. Is there an analytic function $f \colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ with $f(0) = 1/2$ and $f′(0) = 3/4?$ Either find such a function $f$ or explain why it does not exist.

(b) Answer the same question for $f(0) = 1/2$ and $f′(0) = 4/5.$

It seems like I could use the Schwarz lemma, but that is not working out so well.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: Typically one composes the function with $(z-1/2)/(1-(\overline{1/2})z)$; the composition preserves the image as inside the unit circle but now sends $0$ to $0$. Now you can use the Schwarz lemma and so on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The ["Schwarz-Pick"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem) variant of Schwarz's lemma, proved, as Greg Martin's comment suggests, by composing with Möbius transformations of the unit disk, exactly answers your question: a holomorphic function $f\colon \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ must satisfy

$$\frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^2} \le \frac{1}{1-|z|^2}$$

In case (a), the Schwarz-Pick inequality is saturated for $z=0$, so basically the only possible function is the Möbius transformation $f(z) = \frac{2z+1}{z+2}$ taking $0$ to $\frac{1}{2}$, which has derivative $\frac{3}{4}$ there.  In case (b), the inequality forbids such a function.

Comment: but here your f'(0) should be 3/4..

Comment: The answer should be $f(z)=\frac{2z+1}{z+2}$.